# How to run Kafka Connect connect-distributed.sh in the background (daemon)?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I connect to remote host via ssh,
then run

```
./connect-distributed ../etc/kafka/cusom-connect-distr.properties
```

and terminal now is unavailable for input.

I tried `-daemon` option but it doesn't do anything

I also tried to run in background with `&`, but when I close terminal the connect process dies with terminal.

So how I can run connect-distributed in daemon mode ?

Comment: What's your host OS?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your Kafka Connect process runs in the background, but the output logs are reported on standard output.

---

Now in order to direct output to log files you have a number of options:

1. Use `nohup`

```
nohup ./bin/connect-distributed ../etc/kafka/cusom-connect-distr.properties &
```

and the logs will be reported to `nohup.out`

2. Direct standard output and standard error to a file

```
./bin/connect-distributed ../etc/kafka/cusom-connect-distr.properties &> kafka-connect.logs
```

and the output will be under `kafka-connect.logs`

3. Configure Kafka Connect `log4j` properly

By default, `etc/kafka/connect-log4j.properties` looks like:

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %p %m (%c:%L)%n

log4j.logger.org.apache.zookeeper=ERROR
log4j.logger.org.I0Itec.zkclient=ERROR
log4j.logger.org.reflections=ERROR
```

Make sure to change the configuration so that your logs are written to log files. For example,

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, logFile

log4j.appender.logFile=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.logFile.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH
log4j.appender.logFile.File=/tmp/connect-worker.log
log4j.appender.logFile.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.logFile.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %p %m (%c)%n

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %p %m (%c:%L)%n

log4j.logger.org.apache.zookeeper=ERROR
log4j.logger.org.I0Itec.zkclient=ERROR
log4j.logger.org.reflections=ERROR
```

Answer (score 0):

> I tried -daemon option but it doesn't do anything

It should start a background process. You wont see anything in the CLI

Comment: It didn't work until i downloaded connect-distributed script from the newest version of confluent platform
Anyway thank you!)

Comment: @ИльяМаксимов The script that Confluent has is no different than the one that https://kafka.apache.org have

Comment: We use an older version of the Confluent Platform. It seems like there is a bug in the script)

Comment: @ИльяМаксимов To my knowledge, that script has not been updated in years, but [you could have a version even older than this fix](https://github.com/apache/kafka/commit/dca63fc0a50fe268b82ae5bdafa0b876f6389907)